# i need NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle source code

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, bytecode

I need to get into **FluentNhibernate** and **NHibernate** code  so i rebuild the solutions
and used the new assemblies, but the problem is that there is an assembly called
 **NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.Dll** which refuses to load the my own version of **Nhibernate**
and keep telling me that the Public Token doesn't match, so where can i get the source code
for this assembly, so i can reference my NHibernate assembly and rebuild it???

or may be the question is : is it open source ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:$
how stupid I am !!!!

it comes with Nhibernate source code,but what made me confused is when I opened the Nhibernate Solution, the Nhibernate.ByteCode.Castle project wasn't there! !!!

but there is another solution file called NHibernate.Everything.sln, i opened it, and **voila** !!!
there it is in the solution.

Comment: In case anyone else is looking - the source is no longer part of NH trunk as of a March 20th 2011 commit. I haven't been able to find them anywhere else (aside from in the previous revision in the trunk.) See https://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/d22172aec62a2ddd?pli=1

Comment: It looked like it was removed around Mar 20th 2011. Here is the revision in GIT 6bce13fa45f0c7715ca15244474f9dc2612ced95